Has ANYONE been successful building OpenBMC on anything other than an ASPEED SoC?
The title says it all.  OpenBMC seems to be locked to ASPEED SoCs.  Every example, instruction and documentation always seem to return to ASPEED devices, except for a few Raspberry Pi WIPs.
I need to use a more open SoM (which already has a Yocto BSP) so I can use it to run some other things required for our system.
With the name OpenBMC, I would expect it to be, well, more "open".  Sorry, frustration is kicking in a little.
